# React / Node - PayPal AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE with react-paypal-express-checkout

Tags: node.js, reactjs, paypal

Im using react-paypal-express-checkout and today i recognized that i cant do a test payment anymore.
I even load a month old build, where everything was fine but still same error.
So i don't think it's about my code but on the otherhand I've no clue why that error appears

```
details: []
information_link: "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payment-experience/#errors"
message: "Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing Authorization header"
name: "AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE"
```

Thats what my network shows

and my console:

```
Request to post https://cors.api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payment-experience/web-profiles failed with 401 error. Correlation id: unknown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-paypal-express-checkout is not official, was last updated in 2018, and uses an old implementation of the PayPal checkout that is deprecated

Use the current, official [@paypal/react-paypal-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/react-paypal-js)

[Storybook](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/story/example-paypalbuttons--default)